# .load not loading content into element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#result').load('_shared.html body > :not(main)');
});
```

but the `<div id="result" />` element remains empty.

When I open `_shared.html` and run the same selector in the console:

```
$('body > :not(main)').length
```

I get `3` as the result.

In both Firefox and Chrome there are no console errors.

I am using local files (directly from the filesystem, without any webserver), but that doesn't seem to be the issue, as I am running Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` command-line option, and Chrome reports the network request to `_shared.html`.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I work around this?

**Update**

Using Kevin B's answer and comments, I am using the following:

```
$('#result').load('_shared.html > :not(main, title, link, meta)');
```

to insert only direct child elements of the `body`, and to exclude elements defined in the `head`.

Comment: Should this be `body > :not(.main)`?

Comment: I take back what I said.  In the jQuery documentation it states _"The portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded."_  If it works on the page then it should work in the `load()` call.

Comment: What happens if you just do `$('#result').load('_shared.html');`?  (Just to verify it will actually load it).

Comment: @ExplosionPills No it should not. I want to exclude the `main` element, not the elements with the `class="main"` attribute.

Comment: @Archer It does get loaded into the `#result` element.

Comment: `body` doesn't exist, it gets removed by the browser when the string is converted to html.

Comment: This happens because an html document can't contain more than one body. The same happens for the html and head tags.

Comment: Yes, but then all the elements in the `head` are also placed in the `div id=result``.

Comment: Right, but you can't really do anything about that. That's why most examples show how to target a specific element. When jQuery gets access to the html elements, all elements from the head and body are all in the same place, you can't tell what came from where.

Comment: using `$.get` will have the same issue, unless you pre-parse the html with regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector should be `:not(.main)`, because to jQuery `body` doesn't exist in the returned html.

```
$('#result').load('_shared.html :not(main)');
```

Comment: This inserts all the elements on the page, not just the child elements of the `body`.

Comment: unfortunately, due to what i mentioned in the comment in your question, you're going to have to deal with it that way. Change the selector to work with that in mind. Since i don't know what those "other elements" are i can't suggest an alternative.

Comment: Also, see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637290/load-not-loading-content-into-element?noredirect=1#comment36297998_23637290).

Comment: the problem is all elements from the head and body are in the same collection. you can't say only get the ones from body or head, because there is no body or head. They're all in the same div. Adding `>` won't change that.

Comment: If I modify the selector part of the argument -- `_shared.html > :not(main)` it only gives me the direct child elements, not the descendants, which is what I was referring to in my original comment.

Comment: right, because that's what that selector is supposed to do. I don't know what point you're trying to make.